# What are the elements of the Dihedral Group $D_8$ when given by $D_8 = \langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^4=1\rangle?$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

I'm very confused since I've always seen the Dihedral Group $D_8$ given as

$$D_8 = \langle a, b \mid a^4 = b^2 =1, ab= a^3b\rangle.$$

I'm given the Definition

$$D_8 = \langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^4=1\rangle.$$

I want to figure out the elements based on this definition but I don't understand how these definitions differ. I would be incredibly grateful for your help!

Tomato

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Note: $$D_8 = \langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^4=1\rangle$$ and $$D_8 = \langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^4\rangle$$ mean different things.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun! Can you tell me what's the difference or how I can compute it?

Comment: You can compute them using GAP [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Comment: The software and instructions for GAP are available free [here](https://www.gap-system.org/).

Comment: It's like the difference between $$\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^2=1\rangle $$ (which gives the free product $\Bbb Z_2*\Bbb Z_2$ by definition) and $$\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^2\rangle $$ (which gives the amalgamated free product $\Bbb Z*_{\Bbb Z_2}\Bbb Z$), only more complicated; I think the second presentation I gave gives an infinite group (but not $D_8$: that was a copy & paste error).

Comment: (I was wrong about infinity: in GAP, `F:=FreeGroup(2);
rels:=[ (F.1)^2*(F.2)^(-2), (F.1)^2*((F.1)*(F.2))^(-4) ];
Size(F/rels);` produces $48$.

Comment: That is, the group given by $$\langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^4\rangle$$ has order $48$.

Comment: I'd like to give the exact group but (I don't think it matters and) I don't have my laptop handy